# PHP sign in attempts

Tags: php, cookies, session-cookies

I'm trying to restrict user sign in attempts so after the 4th the user will need to wait 10 minutes before attempting again.

I am trying to implement this code:

```html
if(isset($error)) {
 if(isset($_COOKIE["sign-in"])) {
  if($_COOKIE["sign-in"] < 3) {
   $attempts = $_COOKIE["sign-in"] + 1;
   setcookie("sign-in", $attempts, time() + 60 * 10);
  } else {
   echo '<div class="form-error">You have exeeded your sign in attempts, please try again in 10 minutes.</div>';
  }
 } else {
  setcookie("sign-in", 1, time() + 60 * 10);
 }
}
```

Into this:

```html
if (isset($_POST["sign-in-submit"])) {
 $username = $_POST["username"];
 $password = $_POST["password"];
 if ($user->login($username, $password)) {
  header("Location:" . $site_domain);
  exit;
 }
 else {
  $error[] = "Username and password are not correct.";
 }
}
```

So far I have got this which shows the error but still allows sign in if the correct username and password are entered:

```html
if (isset($_POST["sign-in-submit"])) {
 $username = $_POST["username"];
 $password = $_POST["password"];
 if ($user->login($username, $password)) {
  header("Location:" . $site_domain);
  exit;
 }
 else {
  $error[] = "Username and password are not correct.";
  if(isset($_COOKIE["sign-in"])) {
   if($_COOKIE["sign-in"] < 3) {
    $attempts = $_COOKIE["sign-in"] + 1;
    setcookie("sign-in", $attempts, time() + 60 * 10);
    } else {
     echo '<div class="form-error">You have exeeded your sign in attempts, please try again in 10 minutes.</div>';
    }
   } else {
    setcookie("sign-in", 1, time() + 60 * 10);
   }
 }
}
```

What can I do to get this to function correctly?

Comment: Don't use cookies, they could just delete it...

Comment: If you must do this, do it by IP address.

Comment: It's better and but maybe not easier to store number of attempts in the user db

Comment: Bad idea. Doing this makes it easier for unauthorized users to harass real users by locking up their accounts. Instead, when there are repeated login failures on an account within a certain number of minutes, log it and send an alert via text/email to admins.

Comment: What would be the best way to go about this? I'm looking for something simple, but thanks for reminding me about cookies, didn't really think too much about that.

Comment: and don't do it by IP. you could lock out a whole college campus like that.

Comment: Again, this whole approach of auto-locking accounts after a string of failures is a bad idea.

Comment: Database stored is definitely the way to go. If that's to much trouble store login attempts in $_SESSION. Though sessions can easily be destroyed by the user.

Comment: It's a tough one, IP and databases may cause issues for other users though they would be the most secure options, I'm thinking cookies is the best way as the less tech-savvy users wont know how to bypass this. Does anyone know of any other techniques?

Comment: use something like fail2ban and don't worry about it.

Comment: @joedm, you're not worried about less-tech-savvy users. They're not the ones that will be hacking accounts.

Comment: damn yeah, do not use cookies for this, hackers can write write whatever they want in cookies. use a database with logs of recent login attempts.